# RMSE and Average Target Variable

Tags: performance, regression, mean, mse

I have a regression problem and I want to evaluate the performance of my model using:

- RMSE
- MSE
- MAE
- MAPE
- R2
- I am also reporting the average of the target variable in the testing data

Previously my model was achieving an RMSE ~ 40 and the average target variable was 112.

I have changed some columns and the values distributions in my data in order to improve results. The change has impacted both the training and the testing data. Having this said, the average target variable in the testing data is ~ 80.

- RMSE ~ 30
- Average target variable in the testing data: ~ 80

So am I really doing a better job if RMSE has decreased from 40 to 30 ? Or am I fooling myself as previously I had 40 (RMSE)/ 112 (avg. taregt var) vs now I have 30 (RMSE)/ 80 (avg. taregt var)?

In other words, should we really compare the RMSE to the average of the target variable in order to know how well are we doing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The mean doesn't tell you how spread the data is, and a ratio of your RMSE to your mean cannot tell you how much of the variance can be explained by your model.

Since you have it in your list, you can use R2, which is roughly proportion of variance explained, making it invariant to the scale of your target.

Comment: Thank you. The thing that made me think of the average is that the R2 in my model remained the same before and after the change I made, and I noticed the mean of the target variable has decreased as well as the RMSE

Comment: A useful way is to plot your previous predictions against current one, if only the scale has change, they will line up along the diagonal